# Sharing a single laravel database table for multiple queues

Tags: laravel, queue

I've got two separate Laravel applications on the same server that use the same database. Currently App1 was the only one that needed a queue so it ran with the database driver.

Now I'm at the point where I need to run jobs on App2. Can I simply run a queue worker from App2 as long as I keep app1 and app2 on different default queues?

App1 is Laravel 5.4 and App2 is 5.6 (if it matters)

Comment: is App2 queue database driver as well?

Comment: are you using supervisord?

Comment: @HamzaMohamed yes to both

Comment: TBH, I didn't have 2 queues on the same DB, even on localhost .. but I cant see why it shouldnt work, based on queue name which you specify, I believe the below answer is heading that way .. the only thing I would add to the below is you can specify the queue in supervisord .. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39322264/9041947) and there werent any queues updates except for mailQueue since 5.4 and dispatchNow .. you can check it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#mail) .. and for the failed jobs .. `php artisan queue:falied` shows queue name for 5.4 & 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, first some explanation as to how and why:

`php artisan queue:work, listen, etc` will go check the `jobs` db table and execute any pending job located there, if you don't specify the queue on the artisan command all `default` queue jobs will be executed. So yes jobs will be executed but they will fail at the time the two applications differ in the code.

Laravel will serialize payload and that will be executed, but if your payload is unknown to your application of course will fail.

What you can do is "categorize" each queue and only run `app_1` jobs for `App 1` and `app_2` jobs for `App 2`.

So for example you will utilize artisan command like this on App 1

`php artisan queue:work database --queue=app_1`

And this command on App 2:

`php artisan queue:work database --queue=app_2`

So you can see this on the database itself, take a look at the `jobs` table `queue` column you will see all are added to `default` this is what you can specify at the time of registering the queue.

And of course would be best if you upgrade both to L5.6 but they should pretty much work since that has not changed AFAIK.

Reference here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#customizing-the-queue-and-connection
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment