# Running two Laravel projects queues with supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, laravel-queue

Hi below is the `config` file of supervisor of one project

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /livesites/siteA.example.com/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/livesites/siteA.example.com/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Its running fine . I have another project (`siteB.example.com`) with the `redis` as `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in the `.env`. What should the the `config` file for that. Will there be any issue running two projects queues on same server ?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276079/running-multiple-laravel-queue-workers-using-supervisor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First If two projects are on different connections (Redis and Database) shouldn't be any problem.

But if connections are the same (both on Database or Redis), One solution might be using a different queue for each project.

for example in the siteA project push your jobs on siteA queue and in the siteB project push your jobs on siteB queue. Then create two separate supervisor config files and in each of them put `--queue=siteA` or `--queue=siteB` in the artisan command argument.

siteA.conf:

```
command=php /livesites/siteA.example.com/artisan queue:work database --queue=siteA --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

siteB.conf:

```
command=php /livesites/siteB.example.com/artisan queue:work database --queue=siteB --sleep=3 --tries=3
```

and finally, in your Laravel code dispatch each job to appropriate queue:

```
dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('siteA'));
```

in siteB project

```
dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('siteB'));
```

or you can globally change the default queue for each project in config/queue.php as below:

```
'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'siteA' // or siteB, 
    'retry_after' => 90, 
]
```

Comment: if i append --queue=siteA to the supervisor where to use "siteA" in my laravel code ?

Comment: where you are dispatching your job append ->onQueue('siteA')

Comment: can i edit the /confiq/queue.php file and add there in the "queue" instead of specifying when dispatching ?

Comment: Yes, in your connection you can change default to siteA or siteB. 'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'siteA' // or siteB,
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],